# touch on Monitor with TUIO doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: touch, ubuntu-12.04, monitor

I have a touch monitor that use TUIO protocol.
On windows's pc the touch works fine, but not on ubuntu (12.04 version).

Comment: There is not a real [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, which means it cannot be answered. Please put some more effort in your question in thoroughly describing what you have already tried and isolate one specific issue to ask from your endeavors. Also, please have a look at the ['How to ask' section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO.

Comment: I'm guessing you're in need of assist on how to getting it work on Ubuntu - and that the question is not related to any programming issues. In that case, sorry - but this question should be more appropriate on the http://askubuntu.com site of StackExchange.

Comment: ok...I'm sorry. I have a monitor NEC P553 SST that use TUIO protocol and pc zotac with processor intel i3 with ubuntu 12.04. They are connected with HDMI. To use the touch, the monitor manual tells to turn off monitor, connect the monitor and pc with usb, and then turn on monitor. But it doesn't work. Instead on windows all works. I will ask also in askubuntu. Thanks